# ValueError: Protocol not provided to Api Component trying to use O365 to send an email

Tags: python, email, outlook, office365

I'm getting "ValueError: Protocol not provided to Api Component" while trying to send an email through the O365 package. My code is:

```
from O365 import Message

authentication = ('myemail@email.com','mypassword')
m = Message(auth=authentication)
m.setRecipients('myemail@email.com')
m.setSubject('Test')
m.setBody('Test')
m.sendMessage()
```

I tried

```
from O365 import *
```

But I still get the same error. Can someone help me with this problem, please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the protocol for this operation.

```
from O365 import Message, MSGraphProtocol

protocol = MSGraphProtocol()

authentication = ('myemail@email.com','mypassword')
m = Message(auth=authentication, protocol=protocol)
m.setRecipients('myemail@email.com')
m.setSubject('Test')
m.setBody('Test')
m.sendMessage()
```